# Create table views in the cells of a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that contains a list of states. I didn't use a TableViewController to create the table view. I just simply dragged a TableView into the storyboard. I am wondering how to produce a table view in each cell of the state TableView. In the table view inside each state cell I want it to contain another table view that has a list of cities that apply specifically to the state. Example, the "Michigan" cell contains the cities "Detroit" and "Flint", while the "Illinois" cell contains the cities "Chicago" and "Rockford" (each state will contain more than 2 cities, this is just an example.)

Below I have attached my code. Can you please provide clear coding and where to place the new code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

    var states = ["Illinois", "Indiana", "Kentucky", "Michigan", "Ohio", "Pennsylvania", "Wisconsin"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return states.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = states[row]

        return cell
    }

    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        print(states[row])
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your needs it would be much easier to use just one table view. Use a different section for each state. Make the cities the rows of each section. Put the state name in a section header.

Comment: how do i do this any code? @rmaddy

Comment: The answer below is essentially what you want.

Comment: Using a table view within a table view can be a really tricky thing to pull off. Can you post a drawing of what you are trying to achieve as there may be better ways to approach it. Using UIStackViews instead of nested table views springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are asking for sections in a tableview. just try this code to get your result.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mytbl: UITableView!

    var names = ["Illinois": ["Chicago", "Rockford"], "Michigan": ["Detroit", "Flint"]]

    struct States {
        var sectionName : String!
        var sectionObjects : [String]!
    }
    var stateArray = [States]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (key, value) in names {
            print("\(key) -> \(value)")
            stateArray.append(States(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return stateArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stateArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = stateArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return stateArray[section].sectionName
    }

}
```

Comment: i think that may be the best route. Will try it here shortly and let you know @Osman

Comment: nope didn't work. Got an error that reads Thread 1: signal SIGABRT @Osman

Comment: is the view controller name right ? do you have add cell Identifier as "cell"
do you have drag&drop the Delegate and Datasource from your tableview into your view controller ?

Comment: yes I did all that and still receiving error. I've been posting this same question on this site the past 4 days and no one seems to be able to get it. Thanks anyway @Osman

Comment: And the table view isn't a UITableViewController. I just added a table view in so I could adjust the size of it because I plan on putting a logo at the bottom @Osman